# how to cast a spark row(StructType) to scala case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i trying to write a udf function in scala and use that in my pyspark job. 
my dataframe schema is

```
root
|-- vehicle_id: string
|-- driver_id: string
|-- StartDtLocal: timestamp
|-- EndDtLocal: timestamp
|-- trips: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- week_start_dt_local: timestamp
|    |    |-- week_end_dt_local: timestamp
|    |    |-- start_dt_local: timestamp
|    |    |-- end_dt_local: timestamp
|    |    |-- StartDtLocal: timestamp
|    |    |-- EndDtLocal: timestamp
|    |    |-- vehicle_id: string
|    |    |-- duration_sec: float
|    |    |-- distance_km: float
|    |    |-- speed_distance_ratio: float
|    |    |-- speed_duration_ratio: float
|    |    |-- speed_event_distance_km: float
|    |    |-- speed_event_duration_sec: float
|-- trip_details: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- event_start_dt_local: timestamp
|    |    |-- force: float
|    |    |-- speed: float
|    |    |-- sec_from_start: float
|    |    |-- sec_from_end: float
|    |    |-- StartDtLocal: timestamp
|    |    |-- EndDtLocal: timestamp
|    |    |-- vehicle_id: string
|    |    |-- trip_duration_sec: float
```

i am trying to write a udf function

```
def calculateVariables(row: Row):HashMap[String, Float] = {
    case class myRow(week_start_dt_local: Timestamp, week_end_dt_local: Timestamp, start_dt_local: Timestamp, end_dt_local :Timestamp, StartDtLocal:Timestamp,EndDtLocal:Timestamp,vehicle_id:String,duration_sec:Int,distance_km:Int,speed_distance_ratio:Float,speed_duration_ratio:Float,speed_event_distance_km:Float,speed_event_duration_sec:Float)

val trips = row.getAs[WrappedArray[myRow]](4)
```

in this map function i am trying to cast the row to a case class but not able to .i am getting this error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to VariableCalculation.VariableCalculation$myRow$3

can anyone help me how can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.as` on `Row` does just a typecast nothing else. the internal type of `trips` is actually `Row`

so `row.getAs[WrappedArray[Row]]("trips")` will work. then you can `map` over it and construct `myRow` from `Row`.

You could probably do this somehow automatically using Sparks `Encoder` but they're more intended to be applied to an entire Dataset.

have you considered formulating a case class for the entire schema and then just do `dataframe.as[MyCaseClass]` ? that'll give you proper access to the entire nested structure

Comment: thanks i will test out, actually i am from python background new to scala.

Comment: can you give me more idea about how can i map over it ?

Comment: I assume there's a `.map` on `WrappedArray[Row]`

Comment: "formulating a case class for the entire schema" worked the best for me. So much easier.